# CUDA: cudaEventElapsedTime returns device not ready error

Tags: cuda

I tried to measure the elapsed time on Tesla (T10 processors) and cudaEventElapsedTime returns device not ready error. But when I tested it on Fermi (Tesla M2090), it gave me the result.

Can anyone tell me what is happening...

Here is my code

```
cudaError_t err;
        cudaEvent_t start, stop;
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
        err = cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
        f(err != cudaSuccess) {
          printf ("\n\n 1. Error: %s\n\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
          exit(1);
        }
        // actual code
       cudaThreadSynchronize();
        err = cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        if(err != cudaSuccess) {
          printf ("\n\n2. Error: %s\n\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
          exit(1);
        }
        err = cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed_time, start, stop);
        f(err != cudaSuccess) {
          printf ("\n\n 3. Error: %s\n\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
          exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: I figured out the solution for this problem but it would be good if someone tells me why it is happening. So I will keep this question open. The solution is cudaThreadSynchronize()  should be after cudaEventRecord(stop,0)  . If anyone knows what is the reason and why it didn't happen on fermi, let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `cudaEventRecord` is asynchronous. It finishes its execution immediately, regardless of the status. Asynchronous functions simply put an order on a "CUDA execution queue". When GPU finishes its current assignment, it pops the next order and executes it. It is all done in a separate thread, handled by the CUDA driver, separate of your program host thread.

`cudaEventRecord` is an order which says more-or-less something like this: "When you are done all previous work, flag me in this variable".

If your host thread then asks for `cudaEventElapsedTime`, but the GPU didn't finish its work yet, it gets confused and reports "not ready yet!". `cudaEventSynchronize()` stalls the current host thread until the GPU reaches the `cudaEventRecord` order that you placed earlier. After that you are guaranteed that `cudaEventElapsedTime` will have a meaningful answer for you.

`cudaThreadSynchronize()` is just a stronger tool: it stalls current thread until GPU finishes *all* assigned tasks, and not just those until the event.

Comment: Thanks. But why Fermi didn't face that problem? I mean the same code ran successfully and gave the results on Fermi architecture. Why is that so?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe Fermi was fast enough? :)

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue and so based on the answer by @CygnusX1 I keep all my execution code in one cell and the `cudaEventElapsedTime` in another cell. This solved the issue because Colab (or jupyter notebook) goes to the next cell only if the process in the current cell is done.

Thus,

```
with torch.no_grad():
  model.eval() # warm up
  model(x)
  start.record() 
  model(x)
  model(x)
  model(x)
  end.record()
  print('execution time in MILLISECONDS: {}'.format(start.elapsed_time(end)/3.0))
```

raised the error reported in the question i.e. `device not ready error` and was solved by

```
with torch.no_grad():
  model.eval()
  model(x) # warm up
  start.record() 
  model(x)
  model(x)
  model(x)
  end.record()
# Shift the print command to next code CELL !!!
```

```
 print('execution time in MILLISECONDS: {}'.format(start.elapsed_time(end)/3.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are coming from `PyTorch` and you get this error:

```bash
-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/user/projects/ai/mlcrap/fsdp/FSDB_mnist.py", line 159, in fsdp_main
    print(f"CUDA event elapsed time: {init_start_event.elapsed_time(init_end_event) / 1000}sec")
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/streams.py", line 208, in elapsed_time
    return super().elapsed_time(end_event)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device not ready
```

The fix is to sync cuda like this:

```py
# (before)
init_start_event.record()
for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
    train(args, model, rank, world_size, train_loader, optimizer, epoch, sampler=sampler1)
    test(model, rank, world_size, test_loader)
    scheduler.step()

init_end_event.record()
torch.cuda.synchronize() # <---- ADD THIS LINE

print(f"CUDA event elapsed time: {init_start_event.elapsed_time(init_end_event) / 1000}sec")
```